# Lifting State Up And Functional Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble with lifting state up and converting components to functions. What's wrong with my code.

Instructions: 1: Inside the JS section, create a class component named `App`. Inside its `render()` method, have it return the `Welcome` component. In the `ReactDOM.render()` method, change `Welcome` to `App`.

2: Lift the state from the `Welcome` component to `App`, so that the state is initialized inside of `App`'s constructor.

3: Convert the `Welcome` component to a function component that returns the same welcome message as before. You will need to pass the `bootcampName` property of state from `App` to the `Welcome` component. It's up to you whether or not to destructure it.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      bootcampName: "Nucamp"
    };
  }
      render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
            <Welcome  {this.state.bootcampName}>;
            </div>
        );
    };
}
  
function Welcome(props) {
    return (
      <h1>Welcome to {this.props.bootcampName}!</h1>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Please, do not update your question in a way that invalidates the answers. Edit in additional details, maybe at the end, if necessary, but do not include the answers content in your question description.

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors there

- You need to close the Welcome Component.
- You need to name the prop
- Destruct the props in  because of this.state do not exist there.

Here the Code:

```
 class App extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          
          this.state = {
            bootcampName: "Nucamp"
          };
        }
            render() {
              return (
                  <div className="App">
                     { /**
                       *  you need to close the Welcome Component 
                       *  you need to name the prop
                       */}
                  <Welcome  bootcampName={this.state.bootcampName}/>;
                  </div>
              );
          };
      }
        // Here destruct props to use it 
      function Welcome({bootcampName}) {
          return (
            <h1>Welcome to {bootcampName}!</h1>
          );
        }
      
      
      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: update: it's working now. Needed to also do React.Component instead of just Component up top. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Name the prop:

```js
<div className="App">
    <Welcome bootcampName={this.state.bootcampName} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use functional components, you no longer need to use `this`. Try doing this instead:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      bootcampName: "Nucamp"
    };
  }
  render() {
     return (
        <div className="App">
          <Welcome bootcampName={this.state.bootcampName}>;
        </div>
    );
  }
}
function Welcome({bootcampName}) {
  return (
    <h1>Welcome to {bootcampName}!</h1>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you didn't actually pass a prop to your Welcome component. See Jon Warren's response above. You need to do both what he suggested and what I suggested.

Comment: I did both. check out the codepen: https://codepen.io/ganiya/pen/dyGmQqr?editors=0010

Comment: Codepen is showing you an error: `Component is not defined`. You need to import `Component`, or use `React.Component` (which does appear to be in scope for this Codepen)

Comment: update: it's working now. Needed to also do React.Component instead of just Component up top. thanks!!